# android asynctask suddenly stop

Tags: android, sql-server, android-asynctask, jtds

I'm developing app networking from MS SQL using jtdc.
This app is getting movie files from server continuously through AsyncTask.
at One time, 2 or 3 movies is downloaded. But It is not worked well.
For example, when I have to download 3 movie files, I printed log to each of step, 1 and 2 files are downloaded well but last file not. I checked code all, but I don't know why. Also Anything Log is not printed (including try catch). Here is my code(in AsyncTask).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < movieInfoLists.size(); i++) {
                Statement m_Statement3 = conn.createStatement();
                Log.d("DOWN", "0");
                Log.d("FILEKEY>>", movieInfoLists.get(i).fileKey + "");
                ResultSet rs3 = m_Statement3
                        .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM VIEWDATA WHERE MstKeyId=" + movieInfoLists.get(i).fileKey);
                Log.d("DOWN>>", "1");
                while (rs3.next()) {
                    Log.d("r3동작 >>", "1");
                    try {
                        Log.d("r3동작 >>", "2");


                            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs3.getBytes("Phto"));

                            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                                    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"
                                            + movieInfoLists.get(i).fileName));
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int n = 0;
                            long total = 0;

                            while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
                                total += n;
                                output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                            }
                            output.flush();
                            output.close();
                            input.close();
                            Log.d("r3동작 >>", "3");

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("file error 동작 >>", "M1Renewal L.982 "+calCurTime());
                        appendLog("file down drror ioEx" + "> M1Renewal 1089 L." + "TIME : " + calCurTime());
                        movieInfoLists.get(i).fileName = defaultMovieListInfo.get(0).fileName;
                        movieInfoLists.get(i).fileLocalPath = defaultMovieListInfo.get(0).fileLocalPath;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("r3동작 >>", "4");
                    Log.d("DOWN", "다운완료>>>" + movieInfoLists.get(i).fileName);

                }
                rs3.close();
                m_Statement3.close();
            }
```

Here is my log. next no more log. and not performing thread.

test.lee D/사이즈>>>: 3

test.leeD/FILEKEY>>: 55

test.lee D/DOWN>>: 1

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 1

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 2

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 3

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 4

test.lee D/DOWN: 다운완료>>>a.mp4

test.lee D/FILEKEY>>: 58

test.lee D/DOWN>>: 1

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 1

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 2

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 3

test.lee D/r3동작 >>: 4

test.lee D/DOWN: 다운완료>>>b.mp4

test.lee D/FILEKEY>>: 66

test.leetest.lee D/DOWN>>: 1

I guessed rs3 (ResultSet) is a problem. And I founded a solution about this, But I don't find. What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you want to open your sql server to the whole wide world? Wouldn't you be better off getting the data through a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does "movieInfoLists.get(2).fileKey" have correct value? It seems that rs3.next() returns false.

Use Log to print movieInfoLists.get(2).fileKey, and rs3.